# How to update the filtered list in AngularJS without the user's input

Tags: angularjs, filtering

I'm using the [filter](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.filter%3afilter) and everything works nicely when a user types in the input box. What I would like though is to update the filtered results through the code (for example to clear the query), without the user's input. I tried to trigger the change event or simply clear the value of the input field, without any success.

Here is my simplest HTML

```
<div ng-app ng-controller="test">    
    <input type="text" ng-model="query" placeholder="search..">
    <button>Clear</button>
    <ul class="unstyled">
        <li ng-repeat="item in list | filter:query">
            {{item}}
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

And here is the JS:

```
function test($scope) {
    $scope.list = [120, 566, 777, 889, 998, 332, 112, 440, 881];

    $('button').click(function() {
        $('input').val('');
    });
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/usnUR/2/)

What can I do to unfilter the results without deleting the contents of the input using the keyboard, but doing that though the code (like clicking on the clear button)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do not register your event handler via jQuery let `ng-click` handle that for you.

```
<button ng-click="clearBox()">Clear</button>


function test($scope) {
    $scope.list = [120, 566, 777, 889, 998, 332, 112, 440, 881];

    $scope.clearBox = function(){
      $scope.query = "";
    };
}
```

**[Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/markcoleman/usnUR/3/)**